# Disabling accessibility for a table column

Tags: cocoa, macos, accessibility, voiceover

I have a normal NSTableView that displays a list of tracks. I have dedicated a table column to displaying an icon that indicates which track is currently playing.

I'm working on adding fuller VoiceOver support and I don't like how when each row in the table is selected the first thing said is "image". I would like to disable accessibility for that specific table column.

I know I can do this by subclassing either NSTableView and/or NSTableColumn to return YES from accessibilityIsIgnored.  Is there a way to do this without subclassing?

Answer (score 1):

No. There is no such thing as "setAccessibilityIsIgnored" so you need to use a subclass that answers YES when asked -accessibilityIsIgnored.