# Disable accessibility for certain elements in OSX app

Tags: objective-c, macos, osx-mavericks, appkit, voiceover

I have a simple image view. Which I don't want to be read by the accessibility clients. I tried the solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730758/disabling-accessibility-for-a-table-column/3736799#3736799). However this solution didnt work. Also I have one limitation. I want to support OSX 10.9 Hence I cant use [accessibilityElement Property](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nsaccessibility/1535002-accessibilityelement) provided by AppKit since its only available from 10.10

Please let me know a simple way to make certain elements inaccessible for voiceover clients.

Also I would to know the 10.9 equivalent of accessiblityElement.

Answer (score 1):

Most methods in the [NSAccessibility informal protocol](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/1658526-nsaccessibility) were deprecated in 10.10 in favor of property-based accessibility configuration. Prior to 10.10, you would mark elements as accessible (or not) by overriding  [`accessibilityIsIgnored()`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/objectivec/nsobject/1526439-accessibilityisignored).

Answer (score 0):

In modern versions of macOS, you can use `accessibilityElement` for this. When seeking to hide an `NSControl`, though, it's important to use the control's cell to hide the element from all flavors of accessibility. (VoiceOver, Switch Control, Hover Text, etc.) So in the case of an `NSImageView` you would use:

```
myImageView.cell?.setAccessibilityElement(false)
```